# Show that $H+K$ is a subspace of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to solve this, please give me hints.

$H,K \in V$, $V$ is a vector space.
$H+K=\{w:w=u+v:u \in H, v \in K \}$

Show that $H+K$ is a subspace of $V$.

Comment: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/resource/general/121.1.00s/vector_axioms.html Just prove that the space satisfies the vector axioms. Most follow immediately from the definition of $V$.

Comment: This sort of question is designed to help you solidify your understanding of definitions. You should go through and verify that $H+K$ satisfies your axioms/definition of a vector space. You should find it pretty straightforward. You should try this explicitly. Once you've done this, if you still have problems, you can ask a better, more precise question here with which aspect you are having trouble doing.

Comment: But is it alright to prove with axioms using only 2 vectors that are specific such as [1,0] and [0,1]? I feel that would not fully justify that H+K is a subspace of V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sufficient condition is that $H$ and $K$ are subspaces of $V$. It suffices to check if we have $aw_{1} + bw_{2} \in H+K$ for all scalars $a,b$ and all $w_{1},w_{2} \in H+K$.

Let $w_{1},w_{2} \in H+K$ and let $a,b$ be scalars. Then $w_{1} = h_{1} + k_{1}$, $w_{2} = h_{2}+k_{2}$ for some $h_{1},h_{2} \in H$ and some $k_{1}, k_{2} \in K$ by definition. Thus $aw_{1} + bw_{2} = ah_{1} + bh_{2} + ak_{1} + bk_{2}$. But $ah_{1}+bh_{2} \in H$ and $ak_{1} + bk_{2} \in K$  by assumption, so by definition we have $aw_{1} + aw_{2} \in H+K$.

Note that if $H,K$ are simply subsets of $V$, then $H+K$ need not be a subspace of $V$; for if $V := \mathbb{R}(\mathbb{R})$, $H:= \{ 0 \}$, and $K := \{1\}$, then $H+K = \{ 1 \}$, which is not a subspace of $V$.

Comment: I do not understand, $V := \mathbb{R}(\mathbb{R})$. You mean $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: Means the vector space $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{R}$. By the way, if  it is meant $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ then $H$ should be, say $\{ 0 \} \times \{ 0 \}$.

Comment: Also for, $aw_{1} + aw_{2} = ah_{1} + bh_{2} + ak_{1} + bk_{2}$. Do you mean, $aw_{1} + bw_{2} = ah_{1} + bh_{2} + ak_{1} + bk_{2}$?

Comment: What does a vector space $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb R$ mean?

Comment: A vector space is by definition not an object itself. For every vector space there is an underlying field whose elements called scalars. $\mathbb{R}$ is a vector space over the field $\mathbb{R}$. Yes, that is a typo :)