# $W$ is a set, $V$ is a set, then what is $V + W$?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is from my linear algebra problem.
Let $M_{2,2}$ be the space of all $2 \times 2$ matrices. Let $V$ be the set of matrices of the
form 
$$\begin{pmatrix} x & −x\\
y & z \end{pmatrix}$$ 
and $W$ the set of matrices of the form 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 a &b \\
−a &c \end{pmatrix}$$

The problem asked me to find the dimension of $V + W$. However, I'm not sure that $V + W$ means here and how can I find its dimension. I think if it was $V \cup W$ it would be clearer but I doubt that. Can anyone explain? thank you.

Comment: It's usually the set $\{v+w \in M_{2,2} : v\in V, w\in W\}\subset M_{2,2}$

Comment: These are sets of *vectors* (matrices, but they're elements of a vector space, so.. vectors :P), meaning you can add them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that $H+K$ is a subspace of $V$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1434296/show-that-hk-is-a-subspace-of-v)

Comment: Then how do we find the dimension of it ?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format, for future reference.

Answer (score 3):

Your $V$ and $W$ are given by
$$
V = \left\{ \, \left[ \begin{matrix} x & -x \\ y & z \end{matrix} \right] \colon x, y, z \in F  \, \right\}
$$
and
$$
W = \left\{ \, \left[ \begin{matrix} a & b \\ -a & c \end{matrix} \right] \colon a, b, c \in F  \, \right\}
$$
Here $F$ is the field of scalars over which our underlying vector space $M_{2 \times 2}$ is defined.

From the definitions of $V$ and $W$, we note that 
$$ \dim V = 3 = \dim W. $$
A basis for $V$ consists of the matrices 
$$ \left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right], \left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right], \left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right]. $$
And, a basis for $W$ consists of the matrices 
$$ \left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right], \left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right], \left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right]. $$

Moreover, we find that
$$
V \cap W = \left\{ \, \left[ \begin{matrix} x & -x \\ -x & z \end{matrix} \right] \colon x, z \in F  \, \right\}.
$$
Thus we see that
$$ \dim (V \cap W) = 2; $$
in fact a basis for $V\cap W$ consists of the matrices 
$$ \left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right], \left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right]. $$

Hence 
$$
\dim (V+W) = \dim V + \dim W - \dim(V\cap W) = 3 + 3 -2 = 4.
$$

We note that
$$
\dim (V+W) = 4 = \dim M_{2 \times 2}.
$$
And, of course $V+W$ is a subspace of $M_{2 \times 2}$. Therefore we can conclude that
$$ V+ W = M_{2 \times 2}. $$

Let 
$\left[ \begin{matrix} q & r \\ s & t \end{matrix} \right]$ be any element of $M_{2 \times 2}$, where $q, r, s, t \in F$. 
Then we can write
$$
\left[ \begin{matrix} q & r \\ s & t \end{matrix} \right] = \left[ \begin{matrix} q/2 & -q/2 \\ s+q/2 & t/2 \end{matrix} \right] + \left[ \begin{matrix} q/2 & r+q/2 \\ -q/2 & t/2 \end{matrix} \right],
$$
and in the sum on the right the first matrix is in $V$ while the second matrix is in $W$.

Answer (score 0):

$V+W = \mathrm{span}(V\cup W) = \{v+w \mid v \in V, w \in W\}$. You want to determine its dimension a vector subspace of $M_{2,2}$.